# Looking for Geo Spatial Library can be integrate with Hadoop

Tags: hadoop, gis, postgis, arcgis

I am looking for Geo Spatial Library can be integrate with Hadoop. Basically I need to perform few functions like aggregate, extract values of points, dissolve etc. which comes with the ArcGIS.
I looking for something similar that I can do with the Hadoop , using MR or HBase or HIVE whatever is suitable.

Please provide me your suggestions.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

There is a good video on YouTube called [Building a geospatial processing pipeline using Hadoop and HBase with Monsanto](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_JCPf89s-NI) that describes one approach to integrating geospatial data with Hadoop and HBase. They combine GDAL with MapReduce "to convert all geospatial datasets to a common format and projection."

Slides from that presentation are [here](http://www.slideshare.net/Hadoop_Summit/grailer-hochmuth-june27515pmroom212v3).

There are bindings to a variety of different languages with [GDAL](http://www.gdal.org/).

If you like Python, then [Shapely](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Shapely) is a good choice for spatial operations such as dissolve, intersection, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Does [GIS Tools for Hadoop](http://esri.github.io/gis-tools-for-hadoop/) provide what you are looking for?

Comment: Thank you for your response. I am exploring this option already. some of the functions I am able to find out but I don't found functions like Spatial analytics --> Aggregate, Extract Values of Points, Dissolve and even I am not sure how can I achieve DEM (Digital Elevation Modeling).

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Esri' GIS Tools for Hadoop http://esri.github.io/gis-tools-for-hadoop/. You can also check SpatialHadoop from CS Department at University of Minnesota http://spatialhadoop.cs.umn.edu/